# Optimize an image for text recognition using tesseract

Tags: android, opencv, tesseract

I have user tesseract ocr for my android project to recognize text from an image taken from the camera. But the results are not accurate. I want to optimize the image using opencv. I want to achieve the following for the captured image which is decoded in **Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888** format:

1. Detect the objects in the resized image.
2. Once the object is identified, compute its border w.r.t original image. (This is for removing the camera angle effect)
3. Extract the object from original image, by applying perspective transform.
4. Apply white balance to remove lightening effects.

In the example provided by with the tess_two api, they are using **Leptonica** for the image manipulations like drawing the bounding boxes around the words..But in my case I want to use **OpenCV**...Your guidance will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot you are asking for, and depending on the object may be impossible. You should check out the tutorials on 2D feature detection and object detection (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html and http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect.html) to see if there is something you can use.

White balance does not do anything to lighting, you should do adaptive thresholding or some kind of high pass filtering instead.